# Google Mobile Backend Starter not sending message to other instance

Tags: android, cloud, google-cloud-datastore, sample

I am using Google Mobile Backend Starter test application,
As described [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/),

a. [Deployed a backend](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend): Created a sample project

b.  Ran the sample application on 2 android devices ( nexus 3 and S4), using [this code](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android)

So, both devices have same application (i.e with same project ID)

c. Using cloud console I am able to see both devices message coming on cloud datastore.

> But I am not able to see one device message to the other (and vice
>   versa), where as the link states that

***The sample Guestbook app allows you to send messages to other instances of the app.***

> Also, the message comes as 14:57L51 < anonymous >:hi, why anonymous?

What can be the possible reason for the same?

Note:Both devices have different gmail id's. 
[image: S4 device showing only it's own message, not nexus 3 data]

[image: Nexus 3 showing only it's own message,not S4]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to enable google cloud messaging for the same. was missing it earlier.

Steps

1. https://code.google.com
2. select  API's,
3. Turn ON Google Cloud Messaging for Android

Comment: I have the same problem. I have turned ON GCM for Android as well all the other steps explained in the tutorials. Still, the other clients cannot see the messages. Have you got a clue what else I might be missing ? (btw from inspecting GuestBookActivity.java I couldn't find the piece of code responsible for receiving backend notifications)